# Laravel 5.4 http response code before return in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

My question is simple :
Is it possible to set the http response code before the controller method return (if I return a php table, for json response).

I know that it's possible to do that :

```
return response()->json($json,HTTP_CODE);
```

But I want something to set the code somewhere in the controller without modifying the final return.
Or do you know a way to make the native php function http_response_code working ? 
Because Laravel overwrite it during building the Response.
Is it possible ? Or you have to do it in the return ?

I want to know if it is possible to do that or not :

```
 public function myMethod(){
    //Some code
     $this->injectHttpCode(400); //or how to use native native http_response_code(400); ?
    //Some code
    return $this->json; //I dont want to modify that
 }
```

I dont want any "return" in you answer, just tell me if it's not possible.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom middleware? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have some sort of standard way to handle the response code, the easiest way to do is to have a base `BaseController` that contains this:

```
protected function getResponseStatusCode() : int
{
    switch (request()->getMethod()) {
        case 'GET':
        case 'PUT':
            return 200;
        case 'POST':
            return 201;
        case 'DELETE':
            return 204;
        default:
            return request()->getMethod();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public function respond($json) 
{
    return response()->json($json, $this->getResponseStatusCode());
}
```

so in your controller you only call the method in the base controller with:

```
return $this->respond($json);
```

Comment: I know that, please read my question "But I want something to set the code somewhere in the controller without modifying the final return" I have edited my question with an example that I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `response()` function to do something like this:

```
public function myMethod(){
    $response = response();

    //Some code
     $response->setStatusCode(400);

    return $response->json([]);
 }
```